# ¿Cómo concatenar filas de una misma columna en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concat

La cuestión es que tengo que cada asset tenga sus tags, o sea, la número 6 tener en una columna `1,5`, y la asset 1 tener `1,3,5`.
Poniendo literalmente dos veces `asset_tag.tag_id` copia el mismo número de esa fila y lo separa por coma.

"imagen" es esto:

```
CREATE VIEW imagen as
SELECT asset_tag.asset_id  FROM asset_tag GROUP BY  asset_tag.asset_id ;
```

```sql
SELECT asset_tag.asset_id, concat_ws(',',asset_tag.tag_id,asset_tag.tag_id) AS etiqueta

FROM    public.asset_tag 

-- JOIN PUBLIC.imagen ON asset_tag.asset_id = imagen.asset_id

-- WHERE imagen.asset_id = asset_tag.asset_id

GROUP BY asset_tag.asset_id,asset_tag.tag_id

-- HAVING asset_tag.asset_id = imagen.asset_id
;
```

```
asest_id         1     1     1     6     6

tag_id           1     3     5     1     2
```

Que se muestre en tag_id `1,3,5` para el asset_id *1*, y en el caso del asset_id *6* que salgan `1,2`.

Los datos son de tipo integer.

Tengo que llegar a través de una subconsulta pero no lo veo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, muestra siempre el código y la salida _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además... ¿El `GROUP BY` es correcto? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: añadido codigo. si cierto tengo que añadirlo en el primer select

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Disculpa pero no es claro cuál es la pregunta. No es evidente cuáles son los datos de origen ni la salida esperada de la consulta. Recuerda que no sabemos nada de tu problema

Comment: Hmmmm, HeidiSQL es un cliente de base de datos... ¿Qué base de datos estás utilizando? ¿MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle...? Ponlo en las etiquetas.

Comment: se trata de posgresql

Comment: Por favor, pon datos de ejemplo (de nuevo, como texto, con formato). Como te han dicho, no sabemos nada de tu problema, y es muy difícil replicarlo cuando no se tienen datos suficientes. ¿Qué datos hay en _asset_tag_ y en _imagen_? Por cierto, ese `HAVING` ese innecesario si lo mismo está escrito en el `WHERE`...

Comment: si es verdad claro   , disculpa

Comment: la versión 13 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que se está queriendo concatenar *filas de una misma columna*, y no *distintas columnas* (que es lo que se hace al utilizar `CONCAT_WS()`), lo que estarías buscando realmente es utilizar la función de agregación `ARRAY_AGG` dentro de la función `ARRAY_TO_STRING`.

Según la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13):

- `ARRAY_AGG()` *recoge todos los valores de entrada, incluidos los nulos, en un array.* [Documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html)
- `ARRAY_TO_STRING()` *convierte cada elemento del array en su representación de texto, y los concatena por la cadena delimitadora.* [Documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html)

Así, aplicándolo a tu caso:

```
SELECT 
  a.asset_id, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY_AGG(a.tag_id), 
    ','
  ) AS etiqueta 
FROM 
  public.asset_tag AS a
GROUP BY 
  a.asset_id;
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

| asset_id | etiqueta |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1,2 |
| 1 | 1,3,5 |

---

Cabe aclarar que esta salida se produjo con las siguientes sentencias:

```
CREATE TABLE asset_tag (
  asset_id INT,
  tag_id INT
);

INSERT INTO asset_tag VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO asset_tag VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO asset_tag VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO asset_tag VALUES (6,1);
INSERT INTO asset_tag VALUES (6,2);
```

Comment: La función de array llegue hasta ella pero no la conocia y me estaba costando comprenderla, y con esta explicación lo he entendido perfecto . va perfecto gracias ,Millones de gracias !!!

Comment: Edité el título de tu pregunta para que esté acorde a ella. Si falta (o sobra) algo, no olvides volver a editar tu pregunta para mejorarla :)

Comment: oh gracias, cierto , ahora esta mucho mas correcto ‍♀️

Comment: Una ultima duda, cuando en el from se usa lo de " AS " en este caso "a" es para optimizarlo y tarde menos , porque lo he probado con y sin ello y no comprendo la diferencia

Comment: El `AS` es la palabra clave que se utiliza para darle un alias a tu tabla. Fijate que es más legible la consulta al usar el alias, comparando con colocar el nombre completo de tu tabla delante de la columna: `asset_tag.tag_id`, `a.tag_id`. Es más: incluso podés omitir el `AS` ya que _es opcional_, entonces el `FROM` quedaría como `public.asset_tag a`, en este caso.